# chrome addeventlistener animation events

Tags: google-chrome, events, animation, addeventlistener

[greenfloyd.org](http://greenfloyd.org/)

Following code works fine in everything except Google Chrome (Safari not tested).  I think the problem is in the addEventListener registration which is needed to ...

```
**e.addEventListener("animationiteration", listener, false);**
```

fire the **bmViewer()** function

HTML:

```
<div id = **"bmImageDiv"** style = "top:0; left:0; right:0; height:350px; text-align:center; position:absolute; margin:.5em; border-bottom:solid .10em  green; resize:both;">

<img id = "bmIcon" src = "http://greenfloyd.org/images/bookmark.png" alt="bm icon" height = "24" width = "24" title = "poster,timestamp" style = "top:0; left:0; height:25px; width:25px; position:absolute;">

<a href = "javascript:void(0)" id = "bmViewerImageLink" rel = "enclosure" type = "image/*" target = "_blank" title = "click to view image at original size.">

<img id = "bmViewerImageSrc"  src = "http://greenfloyd.org/images/bookmark.png" alt="bm image" height = "95%" width = "95%">

</a>
</div>
```

js:

```
window.onload=function()
{
var e = document.getElementById(**"bmImageDiv"**);
e.addEventListener("animationstart", listener, false);
e.addEventListener("animationend", listener, false);
e.addEventListener("animationiteration", listener, false);
.
.
.
}

function listener(e)
{
switch(e.type) 
{
case "animationstart":
actionLog("Started: elapsed time is " + e.elapsedTime);
break;
case "animationend":
actionLog("Ended: elapsed time is " + e.elapsedTime);
break;
case "animationiteration":
actionLog("New loop started at time " + e.elapsedTime);
var index = document.getElementById("bmNext").value; 
bmViewer(index);
break;
default: 
actionLog(e.type+", "+document.getElementById"bmImageDiv").style.animationPlayState);
document.getElementById("bmImageDiv").className = "play";  
}
}
```

CSS3 animation:

```
@keyframes bmview { from {opacity:0.0; } to {opacity:1.0;} }
@-webkit-keyframes bmview { from {opacity:0.0;} to {opacity:1.0;} }
@-moz-keyframes bmview { from {opacity:0.0;} to {opacity:1.0;} }
@-o-keyframes bmview { from {opacity:0.0;} to {opacity:1.0;} }

.paused
{
-webkit-animation-play-state:paused;
-moz-animation-play-state:paused;
-o-animation-play-state:paused; 
animation-play-state:paused;
}
.play
{
animation: bmview 7s linear 0s infinite;
-webkit-animation: bmview 7s linear 0s infinite;
-moz-animation: bmview 7s linear 0s infinite;
-o-animation: bmview 7s linear 0s infinite;

-webkit-animation-play-state:running;
-moz-animation-play-state:running;
-o-animation-play-state:running; 
animation-play-state:running;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In webkit-based browsers the events `animationStart, animationIteration, etc.` are prefixed by `webkit`. 
So, just add your eventlisteners also for the events `webkitAnimationStart, webkitAnimationEnd, webkitAnimationIteration` and you should be good.

Reference goes [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-animation-javascript-event-handlers/), please also take note of the different prefixes for Opera and IE10

Comment: They are, but with very strange exceptions - at this moment, Im trying to log event. When i open event object in console as tree - there are type equal to "animationstart". But, when i get it in the code - type is equal to "webkitAnimationStart". Dont know, why...

Comment: `Webkit` namespace strikes again ... pfffff